# When i do go build, Getting aws path miss match between github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go and vendor aws

Tags: go

I have run the

`go get github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go`,

After that when i go to my project at  github.com/influxdata/telegraf and run the make command

Getting the following exception

> plugins/outputs/s3/s3.go:277:42: cannot use
> &"github.com/influxdata/telegraf/vendor/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws".Config
> literal (type
> *"github.com/influxdata/telegraf/vendor/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws".Config)
> as type *"github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws".Config in argument to
> "github.***.com/cloud-runtime/cet-***-utils/pkg/client".BuildAuthBlob

**s3.go**

```
import (
"github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
authUtil "github.XXX.com/cloud-runtime/cet-xxx-utils/pkg/client"
)

authBlob, err := authUtil.BuildAuthBlob(&aws.Config{})
if err != nil {
    return defaultReturn, err
}
```

Let me know how i can fix this issue

Comment: Don't use `vendor`. It's obsolete.